# Get count of different types of flows using Metadata API

Tags: apex, metadata-api, visual-workflow

I am trying to get the count of all the components available in the org using Metadata API. But when I try to get the count of flows, it gives me the total count of visual flow plus process builder. I came across [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_visual_workflow.htm) document and I think I need to specify `processType` to differentiate between the flows. I am having issue trying to figure out how to use this in my code. Any idea or help please let me know. Below is my method

```
public Integer getSizeofComponents(String metaType){
        MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
        service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
        service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();

        List<MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery> queries = new List<MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery>();    
        MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery queryLayout =new MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery();
        queryLayout.folder = '';
        queryLayout.type_x = metaType;
        queries.add(queryLayout);
        if(metaType == 'flow')
        system.debug('metaType ----------->> ' + metaType);
        MetadataService.FileProperties[] fileProperties = service.listMetadata(queries, 40);
        if(metaType == 'flow')
        system.debug('fileProperties ----------->> ' + fileProperties);
        if(fileProperties != null){
            return fileProperties.size();
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want is the size/count, just use the Tooling API by querying the [Flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_flow.htm) object:

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
// Change query as necessary
String query = 'SELECT COUNT() FROM Flow WHERE ProcessType = \'Flow\'';
req.setEndpoint(Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/services/data/v42.0/tooling/query?q='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(query,'UTF-8'));
req.setHeader('Authorization','OAuth '+UserInfo.getSessionId());
req.setMethod('GET');
HttpResponse res = new Http().send(req);
Map<String, Object> resAsJson = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
System.debug(resAsJson.get('totalSize')); // outputs total size
```

The listMetadata call doesn't allow filtering, so if you go that route, you need to process ALL the results then parse out the ones you want, while with the Tooling API, you can instantly get the total results without any processing at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Didn't knew I could use processType in SOQL.  This saved me lot of efforts.