# Apex access to Flows

Tags: apex, soql, visual-workflow

I have a datatable with an actions menu on the right side. I want to populate that menu dynamically with the names of Flows that accept inputs of a particular name or SObjectType (that which is displayed in the datatable).

I've read the [Flow.Interview class docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/flow_interview_class.htm#flow_interview_class) so I'm comfortable with how to call the flow from apex and provide the parameters. [Andy in the Cloud](https://andyinthecloud.com/2014/10/26/calling-flow-from-apex/) was quite helpful as well. However, I can't find any reference for doing a SOQL search of Flow.Interview WHERE Name = [whatever].

I've tried `Select Id FROM Flow.Interview` and every variation I can think of... can't figure how to access it. Possible?

Comment: Pretty sure you have to go to the Metadata or Tooling API for this one and walk down into the returned metadata to filter. See under [`FlowVariable`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.218.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_visual_workflow.htm) in the MD API docs here. (Can't say as I've done it myself though).

Comment: Thanks, David. I've been looking at the docs under Tooling API with no luck. I'll check out the Metadata API.  I'll post back here if I can figure out a way to do it.

Comment: In the Tooling API the detail metadata is usually hidden behind a `Metadata` field in the response body, which you can only retrieve one record at a time, for entities that Tooling facades over Metadata.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [this post by @sfdcfox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/213449/get-count-of-different-types-of-flows-using-metadata-api), I found a solution.

```
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    // Change query as necessary
    String query = 'SELECT MasterLabel FROM Flow WHERE ProcessType = \'AutoLaunchedFlow\' AND Status=\'Active\' ';
    req.setEndpoint(Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/services/data/v42.0/tooling/query?q='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(query,'UTF-8'));
    req.setHeader('Authorization','OAuth '+UserInfo.getSessionId());
    req.setMethod('GET');
    HttpResponse res = new Http().send(req);
    Map<String, Object> resAsJson = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
    System.debug(' ' + resAsJson);
```

(Yes, I really do put emojis in my debug comments. Makes it really quick to find things in a log.)

Comment: @David Reed, this solution works from Exec Anon, but in runtime, it gives me a 401 error. I believe I need to configure a Remote Site setting, but I can't figure out what to put in the URL. I've tried the org base Url: `https://yada-yada-9946.cs62.my.salesforce.com`. Also tried it with the `/services/data/v42.0/tooling` appended, but that gets truncated back to the base URL. What am I missing?

Comment: see https://readsalesforce.wordpress.com/2017/08/22/using-metadata-api-to-create-objects-in-salesforce-com-quick-code-snippet-and-demo/ for an example using mydomain. Base URL is all that is required